# Ruby-how to give filename with variable declared

Tags: ruby

I want to create a filename with declared $TENANT variable name.so when I am trying to create a file with variable declared it is taking $TENANT variable as file name but adding ? at the end of the file name

Expected output: 
 $TENANT=cat123dbg

File should be created with `$TENANT` variable i.e `cat123dbg.txt` or any extension.but the file is created with cat123dbg?($tenant variable name with ?)
can someone please help me..

```
    print "Enter the tenant name:"
    $TENANT=gets.chomp('/\p{Alnum}/')
    $first = $TENANT.slice(0,1).capitalize
    $second =$TENANT.slice(1..-1)
    $PASSWORD="Export-"+ $first + $second.chomp + "!"
    FILENAME=$TENANT.chomp + ".xar"
    file = File.open("../input/exporttenant.rb", "r")
    $line = file.readlines.select{|line| line.match('DS_ENTRY_OMS_SERVER')}
    file.close
    output=File.open("../input/#{$TENANT}", 'w')
    output.puts "TENANT_NAME=#{$TENANT}"
    output.puts "EXPORT_PASSWORD=#{$PASSWORD}"
    output.puts "EXPORT_FILENAME=#{FILENAME}"
    output.puts "EXPORT_WITHOUT_TAR=N"
    output.puts "BYPASS_BLOB=N"
    output.puts $line
    output.close

    print "Export tenant created for the #{$TENANT}\n"
```

Comment: Its creating the file name has $TENANT.txt but I want to create with variable name.                                                                                     Expected output:
$TENANT=cat123dbg
File should be created with $TENANT variable i.e cat123dbg.txt or any extension and want to take DS_ENTRY_OMS_SERVER line of the opened file into the cat123dbg.txt file. can someone please help me..

Answer (score 4):

Use string interpolation to replace "$TENANT" with the contents of the variable `$TENANT`.

Instead of...

```
output=File.open("/../Desktop/input/$TENANT", 'w')
```

Do...

```
output=File.open("/../Desktop/input/#{$TENANT}", 'w')
```

Comment: It is creating the file with passed variable $TENANT but it is showing ? at the file creation.                                                                                                        output: devi123
output created                                                                                              file created is devi123?

Comment: Have you verified `$TENANT` has the right value?  You're not modifying `$TENANT` in  your example code, so if you enter (as a second line) `p $TENANT` what's output to the console?